# alpaca forms js - how to make currency field work with reverse?

Tags: alpacajs

Currently on alpaca forms documentation there is no way to start with reverse option. Whatever mask I use I'm always getting the same effect.

Example 1:
Type in currency "5", Field shows: "0,05", Expected behaviour: "5" or "5,00".

Example 2:
Type in currency "100", Field shows: "1,00", Expected behaviour: "100" or "100,00".

Example 3 (working fine):
Type in currency "1,30", Field shows: "1,30", Expected behaviour: "1,30".

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow,

When it comes to third party plugins like here `JQuery Price Format` Alpacajs have nothing to do with what you want to achieve, the documentation you should rely on is the plugin's documentation which is in http://price-format.github.io/Jquery-Price-Format/

Seeing the doc myself I couldn't find what you're looking for, however in their github repo there's a pull-request that stills on validation to fix this issue. (see https://github.com/price-format/Jquery-Price-Format/pull/85)

There's anothing plugin that might be helpful check http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/
and see if it suits you in terms of functions and options, then you can integrate it with alpaca by creating custom field and apply it to your field.